# Why local array value isn't destroyed in function?

Tags: c

```
void func(){
    int i;
    char str[100];
    strcat(str, "aa");
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

int main(){
    func();
    func();
    func();

    return 0;

}
```

this code prints:

```
?@aa
?@aaaa
?@aaaaaa
```

I don't understand why trash `value(?@)` is created, and why `"aa"` is continuously appended. Theoretically local values should be destroyed upon function termination. But this code doesn't.

Comment: Because you never initialize it?

Comment: Before `strcat` do `str[0] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard that says data on the stack needs to be "destroyed" when a function returns.  It's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means anything can happen.

Some implementations may choose to write zeros to all bytes that were on the stack, some might choose to write random data there, and some may chose to not touch it at all.

On *this particular implementation*, it appears that it doesn't attempt to sanitize what was on the stack.

After the first call to `func` returns. The data that was on the stack is still physically there because it hasn't been overwritten yet.  When you then call `func` again immediately after the first call, the `str` variable happens to reside in the same physical memory that it did before.  And since no other functions calls were made in the calling function, this data is unchanged from the first call.

If you were to call some other function in between the calls to `func`, then you'd most likely see different behavior, as `str` would contain data that was used by whatever other function was called last.

Answer (score 1):

To use `strcat()` you need to have a valid string, an uninitialized array of `char` is not a valid string.

To make it a valid "*empty*" string, you need to do this

```
char str[100] = {0};
```

this creates an empty string because it only contains the *null* terminator.

Be careful when using `strcat()`. If you intend two just concatenate to *valid [c](/questions/tagged/c) strings* it's ok, if they are more than 2 then it's not the right function because the way it wroks.

Also, if you want your code to work, declare the array in `main()` instead and pass it to the function, like this

```
void 
func(char *str)
{
    strcat(str, "aa");
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

int  
main()
{
    char str[100] = {0};

    func(str);
    func(str);
    func(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not understood your note. What do you mean saying about "more than 2"?

Answer (score 0):

Function `strcat` means to concatenate two `strings`. So the both arguments of the function must to represent strings. Moreover the first argument is changed.

That a character array would represent a string you can either to initialize it with a string literal (possibly an "empty" string literal) or implicitly to specify a zero value either when the array is initialized or after its initialization.

For example

```
void func(){
    char str1[100] = "";
    char str2[100] = {'\0'};
    char str3[100];
    str3[0] ='\0';
    //...
}
```

Take into account that objects with the automatic storage duration are not initialized implicitly. They have indeterminate  values.

As for your question

> Why local array value isn't destroyed in function?

then the reason for this is that the memory occupied by the array was not overwritten by other function. However in any case it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare:

```
char str[100];
```

all you are doing is declaring a character array, but it's random garbage.

So you are effectively appending to garbage.

If you did this instead:

```
char str[100] = {0};
```

Then you will get different results since the string will be null to begin with. Anytime you allocate memory in C, unless you initialize it when you allocate it, it will simply be whatever was in memory in that spot at the time. You cannot assume it will be NULL and zero'ed for you.